# SQL return the output of SELECT and not the output of another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How do I return the result of the `SELECT` as the output of the stored procedure? Sorry I'm new to stored procedures!

In this query below I'm calling stored procedure `spCuExt_ExtractLog` and assigning the result to variable `@StartDate`. I then use this variable within the main stored procedure, in a `SELECT` statement. I need to return only the result of the `SELECT` statement from the main stored procedure:

```
-- Main stored procedure
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME

    EXEC @StartDate = spCuExt_ExtractLog 'Customers'

    SELECT Id, [Name], LogoPath, IsDeleted
    FROM dbo.Customers 
    WHERE RecordCreatedDateUTC>= @StartDate
END
```

This returns the result of the call to `spCuExt_ExtractLog` as well as the result of the `SELECT` statement but I want to output the result of the `SELECT` only.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you have `select` statement present in `spCuExt_ExtractLog` procedure ? If no, then only the select present in your second proc will be displayed as result

Comment: @Pரதீப் - Yes, SELECT max(date) from Extract where ID=@id

Comment: If you don't want the select result present in first procedure then remove the select query..

Comment: @Pரதீப் - I would need the select in storedProcedure1 because it has to return a date which will be used in storedprocedure2

Comment: `Select` result will not be stored in the variable as you expect, your understanding is wrong. Only when there is a output parameter in the first stored procedure, you can assign value to variable like that else `0` will be your result and it will be implicitly converted to `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return only the last select results from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867321/return-only-the-last-select-results-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the results into a table variable instead:

```
create procedure dbo.usp_Child
as
begin
    select N'Hello world!' as [message];
end;
go

create procedure dbo.usp_Main
as
begin;
    declare @results table ([message] nvarchar(max));

    insert into @results
    execute dbo.usp_Child;

    select N'success';
end;
go

execute dbo.usp_Main;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to a pretty good document explaining all the different ways to solve your problem (although a lot of them can't be used since you can't modify the existing stored procedure.)

http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html